# Load more in table drag

Tags: 7

I'm using drupal table drag functionality for displaying a group of taxonomy terms and content types. Code is obtained from drupal examples.

Need to find out how to use load more functionality. My aim is to display 3 childrens of a parent. Then after clicking load more button, next set of siblings will be displayed.

Tried to use **ajax_command_after** in load more callback, but don't know how to use **theme()** to load the next set of siblings.

Please help if anyone knows. Im not using any views here..

[image]

My load more button is,

```
    'load_more' => array(
        '#type' => 'button',
            '#submit' => array('load_more_submit'),
            '#value' => 'Load More',
            '#name' => $item->id,
        '#ajax' => array(
           'callback' => '_ajax_load_more',
           'event' => 'click',
           'method' => 'append'),
        ),
```

Comment: `Im not using any views here..` then don't tag your question with  `draggable-views`, a module that uses Views. Also, you should add your Drupal version `7` or `8` tag.

Comment: Can't find a tag nearer to drag table, that's why.. Any idea with my query??